# API with Basic Authentication - credential rotation

Tags: api, azure-data-factory, basic-authentication, azure-keyvault

I have a solution that uses a 3rd party API which is secured with some sort of Basic Authentication secret. I have no control over that API but the keys are getting rotated every now and again. What would be the safest way for that API to notify me of credential changes. I want to rule out as much manual work as possible.

The solution that I have is a Azure DataFactory and keys are stored in KV

Answer (score 1):

***To get the notification whenever the Key Vault credentials are changed you can make use of Azure Logic Apps like below:***

*Go to Azure Portal -> Azure key vaults -> Your Key vault -> Events ->Get started -> Select Logic Apps -> Sign - in with your account -> Continue*

[image]

Click **When a resource event occurs** screen, do the changes like below:

[image]

***Choose an operation -> Select All -> Select your required email provider -> Select -> Send an Email***

[image]

Edit the Email template by including **`to`**, **`subject`**, **`body`** save and Create.

*Whenever you make changes on secrets, you will receive notification to your email.*

**Reference**:

[Email when Key Vault status of the secret changes | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/event-grid-logicapps)